# Loading screen when navigating between routes in Angular

Tags: css, angular, typescript

I tried to add a loading spinner to my project but it's not working for me. How do I show a loading screen when I change a route in Angular.

here is my HTML page

```
<div *ngIf="showLoadingIndicator" class="spinner"></div>
```

Here is my component.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Event, Router, NavigationStart, NavigationEnd,NavigationCancel,
  NavigationError } from '@angular/router';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-home-page',
  templateUrl: './home-page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home-page.component.scss']
})
export class HomePageComponent implements OnInit {
  
  loading = true
  showLoadingIndicator = true;


  constructor(public router: Router) {
    this.router.events.subscribe((routerEvent: Event) => {
      if (routerEvent instanceof NavigationStart) {
        this.showLoadingIndicator = true
      }
      if (routerEvent instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        this.showLoadingIndicator = false
      }
      if (routerEvent instanceof NavigationError){
        this.showLoadingIndicator = false
      }
      if(routerEvent instanceof NavigationCancel){
        this.showLoadingIndicator = false
      }
    });

  }
```

this is CSS style sheet

```
.spinner {
  border :16px solid silver;
  border-top: 16px solid #337AB7;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  animation: spin 700ms linear infinite;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;

}
@keyframes spin {
  0% {transform: rotate(0deg)}
  100%{transform:  rotate(-360deg)}
}
```

Can anyone tell me what is the issue? thank you in advance

Comment: It looks good. But have a look at following [tutorial](https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/angular-loading-spinners-with-router-events). That's how it worked for me.

Comment: Is the background silver too? And position: absolute - is it within another element 
 https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp (And what purpose does loading serve)

Answer (score 0):

Place the spinner at the same level of the Router outlet, (you can have more than one in your application, hence the location of the spinner depends on your use case scenario)

Then in the class generate an obervable with the router events, filter the stream to only emit the starting/termination events and map them to a boolean,

Additionally you can tap on that and add a side effect to render some label, but this is not required and there is a long discussion about observables and side effects, but in this case, the side effects are minimal and you are saving subscribe/unsubscribe manually to the observable, which makes the code cleaner.

CSS were omitted for brevity.

```html
<theme-navbar>
</theme-navbar>
<loading-spinner
    *ngIf="loading | async; else routerOutlet"
    label="{{status}}"
    size="extra-large"
></loading-spinner>
<ng-template #routerOutlet>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</ng-template>
```

and the class would look like:

```js
import { Component, OnInit, inject } from '@angular/core';
import { NavigationCancel, NavigationEnd, NavigationError, NavigationStart, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { filter, map, tap } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    
    status = '';

    loading = inject(Router).events.pipe(
        filter((e) =>[ // only react to start and finish events
            NavigationStart,
            NavigationEnd,
            NavigationError,
            NavigationCancel
        ].some((constructor) => e instanceof constructor)),
        map((e) => e instanceof NavigationStart),
        // this line saves us to have to manually subscribe to the stream
        tap(e=>{this.status = e ? 'navigating' : 'done'})
    );
}
```